# Ocelot Rate Limiting

Tags: api-gateway, rate-limiting, ocelot

I've been using Ocelot lately to build an API Gateway. Are rate limits based on the requester client id? Because i've been asked to build an api gateway in an architecture that will look like this

[image]

And all the requests will have the same id since they are passing through the proxy.
I can however, identify the different requesting clients using an header token. So my question is: can i limit the number of request made by a client using the header token rather than the request id? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use Ocelot as a Rate Limiter based on ClientId.

```
"RateLimitOptions": {
"DisableRateLimitHeaders": false,
"QuotaExceededMessage": "Customize Tips!",
"HttpStatusCode": 999,
"ClientIdHeader" : "MY-CLIENT-ID"
}
```

The last line in [Ocelot's rate limiting](https://ocelot.readthedocs.io/en/latest/features/ratelimiting.html) documentation refers to this:

> **ClientIdHeader** - Allows you to specifiy the header that should be used to identify clients. By default it is “ClientId”

You could also implement your own middleware and use Ocelots rate limitng. So You could be able to read other Headers and get your customized client-id:

Just take a look at default rate limiting middleware provided by Ocelot: [ClientRateLimitMiddleware.cs](https://github.com/ThreeMammals/Ocelot/blob/develop/src/Ocelot/RateLimit/Middleware/ClientRateLimitMiddleware.cs)

```
public virtual ClientRequestIdentity SetIdentity(HttpContext httpContext, RateLimitOptions option)
    {
        var clientId = "client";
        if (httpContext.Request.Headers.Keys.Contains(option.ClientIdHeader))
        {
            clientId = httpContext.Request.Headers[option.ClientIdHeader].First();
        }

        return new ClientRequestIdentity(
            clientId,
            httpContext.Request.Path.ToString().ToLowerInvariant(),
            httpContext.Request.Method.ToLowerInvariant()
            );
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

An easy and good solution for me was to add the "ClientId" in the header as soon as I got the JWT token validation.

```cs
    // Authentication
    builder.Services.AddAuthentication(options =>
    {
        options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        options.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        options.DefaultScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    }).AddJwtBearer(options =>
    {
        options.Authority = builder.Configuration.GetSection("OAuthSettings:Authority").Get<string>();
        options.TokenValidationParameters = new Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.TokenValidationParameters
        {
            ValidateIssuer = true,
            ValidateAudience = true,
            ValidAudiences = builder.Configuration.GetSection("OAuthSettings:Audiences").Get<string>().Split(';')
        };
    
        options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
    
        options.Events = new JwtBearerEvents
        {
            OnAuthenticationFailed = context =>
            {
                return Task.CompletedTask;
            },
            OnTokenValidated = context =>
            {
                // Adding the ClientId in the header
                // It is used by the rate limiting
                string clientId = context.Principal.Claims.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Type == JwtClaimTypes.ClientId).Value;
                context.HttpContext.Request.Headers.Add("ClientId", clientId);
    
                return Task.CompletedTask;
            },
        };
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
{
  "Routes": [
    {
      "DownstreamPathTemplate": "/weatherforecast",
      "DownstreamScheme": "https",
      "DownstreamHostAndPorts": [
        {
          "Host": "localhost",
          "Port": 7094
        }
      ],
      "UpstreamPathTemplate": "/gatewaycheck",
      "UpstreamHttpMethod": [ "Get" ],
      "UpstreamHeaderTransform": {
        "ClientId": "MyClient"

  },
  "RateLimitOptions": {
    "ClientWhitelist": [ "MyClient" ],
    "EnableRateLimiting": true,
    "Period": "15s",
    "PeriodTimespan": 1,
    "Limit": 1

  }
}


 ]
  }
```

Try this!!!!

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).